# Repair Local Visual Studio TFS Workspace Mapping to the previous location

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs

I had issues with my laptop so I had to reinstall windows, How can I remap to the previous workspace
I would like to repair or map to the previous local files that Visual Studio was been linked. Does anyone know this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS workspaces are unique to your user name and the remote computer name and workspace information is stored both on your local computer and on the server.

Genearlly if the machine name not changed, the previous workspace will be still available when you connect to the team project.

However if the machine name changed, the previous map will be not available any more. In this case, you can try to delete the existing workspace, or change the mappings (`suggest you copy the workspace folder for a backup first`). You can select the `Workspace` menu in `Source Control Explorer`, and select `Workspaces...` to open the Manage Workspaces dialog.

Alternatively create a new workspace and map to the previous folder, when get latest it will popup the resove conflicts dialog, just select all the conflict files and click `Keep Local File Contents`.

If that still not work, just try to add files manually:

1. Copy previous workspace folder for backup first in case destroyed
   the local changes.
2. Delete the `$tf` foder in the previous workspace (By default the
       folder is hidden,  `View > Hidden items` to show the folder)
3. Creat a new workspace and map to the previous folder
4. Select the new workspace in `Souce Control Explorer`
5. Right click the `Team Project` in `Souce Control Explorer` --> `Add
   items to Folder...`
6. Select all files then **Finish** --> Right click the `Team Project`
   --> `Get latest version`  --> Resolve the conflicts --> `Keep Local File Contents`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the machine name changed, you probably better off remapping a new workspace and copying any changed files over into the new workspace.